# If I had a price chart with a slope of 0.4 and I simulated random buy and sell orders on it, what would make it equivalent to a slope of zero?

Tags: factoring, regression, slope

If I was making random buys for, say $100 worth of shares and selling at random times my gains would would increase by the degree of the slope of the price series. But what if I modified the losses to be larger than they were? How much would I have to increase the losses by a factor of in order for the slope of the price chart to be flat?

What change to the losses would make random buying and selling reflect a price chart that was flat, had a slope of 0 instead of a slope of 0.4? In other words, I want all gains and losses to add up to zero.

So, to do this I would multiply all losses by something like 1.4? Would adding just a one to the slope do it? What is the formula for this?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll call random variable $X$ the increase or decrease in your the $y$-axis each step. So, $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0.4$ is the slope of the trend line.

We can break this up into the increase and decrease case.

$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X|X\ge0]P(X \ge 0) + \mathbb{E}[X|X<0]P(X < 0) .$$

Now consider random variable $Y$ to be the modified version of $X$ after multiplying all the drops. You want $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$ and we'll assume $\mathbb{E}[X|X\ge0] = \mathbb{E}[Y|Y\ge0]$, and $P(X \ge 0) = P(Y \ge 0)$, which also means$P(X < 0) = P(Y < 0)$ since $P(X \ge 0) = 1-P(X < 0)$. Interpretation is we don't change how likely a drop is or the expected value of an increase, only change the expected value of a drop. Then, we have

$$ \mathbb{E}[Y] = 0 = \mathbb{E}[X|X\ge0]P(X \ge 0) + \mathbb{E}[Y|Y<0]P(X < 0) .$$

If you want to know $\frac{\mathbb{E}[Y|Y<0]}{\mathbb{E}[X|X<0]}$, i.e. the value to multiply the drops by, you can work out the algebra and find that

$$ \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y|Y<0]}{\mathbb{E}[X|X<0]} = -\frac{\mathbb{E}[X|X\ge0]P(X \ge 0)}{\mathbb{E}[X|X<0]P(X < 0)} = 1-\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\mathbb{E}[X|X<0]P(X < 0)}.$$

In other words, knowing that $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0.4$ is not enough to answer your question. You also need the value of $\mathbb{E}[X|X<0]P(X < 0)$, which you can interpret as the average drop value multiplied by the probability of a drop.

Edit: "increase" = "gain", and "decrease" = "drop" = "loss", sorry if my terminology is sloppy

Comment: Right. I guess the more prices above and below the best fit linear regression line would effect the profit and loss. I didn't think of that. Thank you. Though would you be able to add what the answer to my question might be if price chart was totally straight? Just a straight line at a slope of 0.4 and I bought and sold randomly?

Comment: Doesn't a straight line with positive slope just mean no losses?

Comment: You got me there. Duh. What if the variance above and below the slope was equal? Like the teeth of a saw. Would there be a way to figure out what factor to apply to the negatives to make it as if it was a slope of zero?

Comment: In that case yes. For the formula above, $P(X<0)$ would how often the saw is sloping down, presumably 0.5 but could be something else. $\mathbb{E}[X|X<0]$ is the slope when the saw is sloping down, and $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is the net slope of the saw, i.e. slope of the trend line.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what these symbols mean. I'd like to learn. I know 'E' is expectation, but I'm not quite sure what that means exactly. I know the 'greater than symbol.